# Complexity function of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to find the  worse case complexity function of this algorithm considering comparisons statement as the most relevant operation. That's when the `if` and  `else if` are both always executed under the loop, so the function is 2*number of loop executions.

Since the variable `i` is beeing increased by a bigger number each time the complexity is probably O(log n) but how do i find the exac number of executions? Thanks.

```
  int find ( int a[], int n, int x ) {    
  int i = 0, mid;
  while ( i < n ) {
     mid = ( n + i ) / 2;
     if ( a[mid] < x )
        n = mid;
     else if ( a[mid] > x )
        i = mid + 1;
     else return mid;
     }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop size decreases by half for every execution. So if you have n elements, then pow(2,x) = n. where x = number of iterations.(because in worst case, loop terminates when i >=n )., So x = log2 (n).

Comment: *"Since the variable i is beeing increased by a bigger number each time"* - no it's not: if it's being increased (because `x` is still greater than `a[mid]`), it'll be by half as much each time - i.e. increased by a smaller number each time.  Anyway... "probably O(log n)" is correct... more specifically O(log-base-2(N)).  *"but how do i find the exac number of executions?"* to find the *"worse case complexity function"* you don't need the exact number of executions; complexity analysis ignores constant factors, and needing to keep halving the search is the worst case.

Comment: Thanks guys, can you explain me why log(2,n) when the else if  is true ? I can see that when the  if statement  is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Qualitative Understanding

---

Well let's try to look at the loop invariant to figure out *how long* this function is going to run.

We can see that the function will continue to execute code until this `while(i < n){ ... }` condition is met.

Let's also note that within this `while` loop, `i` *or* `n` is *always* being mutated to some variation of `mid`:

```
if ( a[mid] < x )        # Condition 1:
    n = mid;             #   we set n to mid
else if ( a[mid] > x )   # Condition 2:
    i = mid + 1;         #   we set i to mid+1
else return mid;         # Condition 3: we exit loop (let's not worry about this)
```

So now let's focus on `mid` since our `while` condition always seems to be getting cut down depending on this value (since the `while` condition is dependent on `i` and `n`, one of which will be set to the value of `mid` after each loop iteration):

```
mid = ( n + i ) / 2;     # mid = average of n and i
```

So effectively we can see what's going on here after looking at these pieces of the function:

> The function will execute code while `i < n`, and after each loop iteration the value of `i` or `n` is set to the average value, effectively cutting down the space between `i` and `n` by half each time the loop iterates.

This algorithm is known as a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), and the idea behind it is we keep cutting the array boundaries in half each time we iterate in the loop.

So you can think about it as **we keep cutting `n` in half until we can't cut in half anymore**.

### Quantitative Analysis

---

A mathematical way to look at this is to see that we're effectively dividing  `n` by 2 each iteration, until `i` and `n` are equal to each other (or `n < i`).

So let's think about it as **how many times can we divide our n by 2 until it equals 1**? We want our n to equal 1 in this case because that's when we are unable to split the list any further.

So we're left with an equation, where `x` is the amount of time we need to execute the `while` loop:

```
n/2^x = 1
n = 2^x
lg(n) = lg(2^x)
lg(n) = x lg(2)
lg(n) = x
```

As you can see, `x = lg(n)` so we can conclude that your algorithm runs in `O(lgn)`